# SQL Server 2008 R2 MERGE statement to replace single INSERT AND UPDATE statement combined

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

for performance reasons, we're considering changing our standard stored procedure for saving data (INSERT and UPDATE combined in a single stored proc):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCustomerSave]
    (
        @CustomerID int = null,
        @CustomerName nvarchar(50),
        @New_ID int output
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblCustomer WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE tblCustomer
            SET 
                CustomerName = @CustomerName
            WHERE
                CustomerID = @CustomerID;
                SELECT @New_ID = @CustomerID;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tblCustomer(
                Taalnaam)
            VALUES(
                @CustomerName)
                SELECT @New_ID = scope_identity();
        END
    END
```

into a syntax using the MERGE statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCustomerSave]
    (
        @CustomerID int = null,
        @CustomerName nvarchar(50),
        @New_ID int output
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT @New_ID = @idTaal;

    MERGE dbo.tblCustomer as target
        USING (SELECT @CustomerID, @CustomerName) as source (CustomerID, CustomerName)
        ON (target.CustomerID = source.CustomerID)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET 
                CustomerName = @CustomerName
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (CustomerName)
            VALUES(source.CustomerName);
                SELECT @New_ID = scope_identity();
    END
```

Question:

- is this going to benefit us performance wise? (avoiding the initial SELECT on the primary key)
- is this proper use of the MERGE statement? Most examples show MERGE statements in a scenario to execute multiple DML operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done any comparative testing of the two (yet) nor seen any articles on the topic. There is an [Optimizing MERGE Statement Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317.aspx) article on Technet but this doesn't include any comparisons with the update/insert syntax.

I can however suggest an improvement over your original syntax which eliminates the `IF EXISTS` lookup:

```
UPDATE 
    dbo.tblCustomer
SET 
    CustomerName = @CustomerName
WHERE
    CustomerID = @CustomerID;

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT @New_ID = @CustomerID;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT 
        dbo.tblCustomer
        (Taalnaam)
    VALUES
        (@CustomerName);

    SELECT @New_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

You may also be interested in [Mythbusting: Concurrent Update/Insert Solutions](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/), which includes some examples of `MERGE` usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that your table would have to be incredibly large and improperly indexed or have hundreds-to-thousands of concurrent users running this proc (the merge uses 1 less lock) to really see any sort of performance difference between the 2 statements.